# Parsing after String.split() and null values

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse string after split to int. I receive null values while printing this.

```
public class Usage {
    public int[] vectorA, vectorB; public String value; 
    public String[] valueSplittedA, valueSplittedB;

    public void scan(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        value = sc.nextLine();
    }

    public void scanLine(){ //Get users values for vectors
        System.out.println("Enter the first Vector\n");
        scan();
        valueSplittedA = value.split(" ");
        System.out.println("Enter the second Vector\n");
        scan();
        valueSplittedB = value.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i<valueSplittedA.length; i++){
            String temp = valueSplittedA[i];
            vectorA[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<valueSplittedB.length; i++){
            String temp = valueSplittedB[i];
            vectorB[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        }
        System.out.println(vectorA);
        System.out.println(vectorB);
    }

}
```

Main method:

```
public class Five {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Usage usage = new Usage();
        usage.scanLine();
    }
}
```

Both prints of vectors shows null. Whats wrong?

Comment: I don't see any code to actually instantiate those arrays, though I see the declaration up at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your arrays. Here's the full working program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import cern.colt.Arrays;

public class Usage {
    public int[] vectorA, vectorB; public String value; 
    public String[] valueSplittedA, valueSplittedB;

    public void scan(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        value = sc.nextLine();
    }

    public void scanLine(){ //Get users values for vectors
        System.out.println("Enter the first Vector\n");
        scan();
        valueSplittedA = value.split(" ");
        vectorA = new int[valueSplittedA.length];
        System.out.println("Enter the second Vector\n");
        scan();
        valueSplittedB = value.split(" ");
        vectorB = new int[valueSplittedB.length];
        for(int i = 0; i<valueSplittedA.length; i++){
            String temp = valueSplittedA[i];
            vectorA[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
       }
        for(int i = 0; i<valueSplittedB.length; i++){
            String temp = valueSplittedB[i];
            vectorB[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vectorA));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vectorB));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Usage u = new Usage();
        u.scanLine();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your vector variables.

```
public int[] vectorA, vectorB; <-- declared but not initialized
```

Thus it throws a `NullPointerException` when doing :

`vectorA[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp);`

When you will fix that, I assume that you want to print the content of `vectorA` and `vectorB` so do :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vectorA));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vectorB));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vectorA = new int[valueSplittedA.length];
for(int i = 0; i<valueSplittedA.length; i++){
    String temp = valueSplittedA[i];
    vectorA[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
}
```